# How to set start page dynamically

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I have an Onsen UI app with an ons-navigator. What is the appropiate way to set the first page to be displayed dynamically on app start? The page to be displayed will be chosen depending on some parameters stored in local storage.

Comment: open your db, and obtain your conditions and use setcontentview.. or navigate to that particular activity.. do the checking in the oncreate.. onresume is when the ui is surfaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
ons.ready(function() {
    navigator.resetToPage(window.localStorage.getItem('currentPage'))
});
```

It will reset the navigator page stack so it only has one page.